# Testlink: How do I easily attach an image to a test case?

Tags: testlink

I'm new to TestLink and just got the bitnami virtual machine version up and running. I've been trying out the software and so far it hasn't been too difficult to figure out, but now I've run into an issue where there doesn't appear to be an easy way at all to get an image on my PC to show up in a test case step for the expected result.

In the test suite I can upload the image as an attachment and have it show it there, but I don't see a way to link this to the test case. The test case editor can insert images from URL, but has no option to upload an image or use an image already on the server. I tried the inline image text as well, but all it does is show what I typed, in this case `[tlInlineImage]2[/tlInlineImage]`. The image is not rendered.

Can anyone with TestLink experience give me some tips on how to do this?

I'm running the latest bitnami image with TestLink 1.9.14.